# Indentation in caption after the first line

Tags: captions, indentation

I have long captions for my tables and figures and I want my captions to be indented 3 characters after the first line. For example

```
Table 1.1. bla bla bla  
...bla bla bla  
...bla bla bla
```

`.` above represents a single character.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) offers an `indention` key-value for setting the indentation of lines following the first line:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,graphicx}
\captionsetup[table]{
  indention=1.5em
}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. 
     Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
     Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis 
     enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus 
     ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I've used the horizontal font-specific width of `em`s (specifically, `1.5em`). However, you may want to `ex`s, or some other measure. Regular Computer Modern font has a variable character width. If need be, one can calculate the width of three (of your favourite) characters, and use that measurement.